# Nautilus 3.4 on Ubuntu-Gnome 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, nautilus

I'd like to get Nautilus 3.4 on a fresh install of Ubuntu-Gnome 14.04. Nautilus 3.10 is the earliest version available through the default repositories.

There are instructions around for earlier versions of Ubuntu but they don't directly work for 14.04 and I don't know enough about apt-get to tell why or adapt them.

Comment: Why do you want the older version of Nautilus?

Comment: @CharlesGreen Because they have removed features that I want.

Comment: I think many of the deprecated features were rolled into Nemo, which I was using before I switched to gnome.  There's a good article about installation and integration of nemo on [webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/install-nemo-220-with-unity-patches-in.html)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to install older version of packages on Ubuntu ,theortically possible this but not pratically.

```
$apt-get install -f <old vesrion>
```

But your system will have broken packages.
Thus you should rebuild the packages in this case.

The process is as following:

1) Get the repository from the [Nautilus 3.4 version](https://launchpad.net/debian/wheezy/+source/nautilus) (you can get it from launchpad).

2) Rebuild this on 14.04.
In the sources directory.

```
$dpkg-source -x nautilus-3.4xxx.dsc
$cd nautilus-3.4xxx
$debian/rules build
$dpkg-build package
```

3) After then you can install nautilus rebuilt from the local directory.

```
$dpkg -i nautilus-3.4xxx.deb
```

Comment: Not going to work.

Comment: Why do you install old version?